# How to setup android App for the first time?

Tags: android, sqlite, installation

In my program how do I setup my SQLite DBs for the first time? What is the program structure to do this?

only way i can think of is to keep a first time boolean:

if (isFirstInstall) setup();

this seems very unprofessional. Are there onFirstInstall() calls where these kind of setup is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
private SharedPreferences mPreferences;

    boolean firstTime = mPreferences.getBoolean("firstTime", true);
    if (firstTime) { 
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("firstTime", false);
        editor.commit();
        showMiddleActivity();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can store a boolean into SharedPreferences, and check the value(first time or not)
when the application starts.

check the documentation of [sharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

hope this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3010867/726547) helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code.

Call **checkFirstLaunch();** from onCreate().

```
private boolean checkFirstLaunch() {
        try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
            //int currentVersion = info.versionCode;
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            int lastVersion = prefs.getInt(PreferencesActivity.KEY_HELP_VERSION_SHOWN, 0);
            if (lastVersion == 0) {
                isFirstLaunch = true;
            } else {
                isFirstLaunch = false;
            }

        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, e);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

You get boolean result.

```
if (isFirstLaunch) {
    //code    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of figuring out wether it's the first time you start up you could check if the db is there or not and create it if it's missing.

```
public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    if ( checkIfDataBaseExist() ) {
        // db exists, do nothing
    } else {
        // By calling this method and empty database will be created into
        // the default system path of your application
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            // Do you db copying here
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

private boolean checkIfDataBaseExist() {
    File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    return dbFile.exists();
}
```